# opencart: I can edit order but cannot delete it. (with Error log)

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I use opencart version **2.1.0.1**

Everytime I click **`admin > sales > order`**, it will pop up **`"error undefined."`** By closing that popup window, I can still edit order but cannot delete order (no response).

In my log, there is:

> **PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: order_id in**
>
> **`/var/www/html/opencart2101/system/storage/modification/admin/view/template/sale/order_list.tpl on line 821`**
>
> **The line 821 is:**
>
> **`url: 'index.php?route=extension/openbay/addorderinfo&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>&status_id=' + status_id,`**

However, I haven't installed any openbay related module. Also, line 821 is inside **`<!-- -->`** mark. It should have no effect.

Help!

Comment: I delete the code around line 821. But same error message and some error log...odd

Comment: Make sure you have assigned API user and have proper API settings. This error comes when order controller tries to get session cookie for API calls.

Comment: Thanks! API is enabled, though I an not sure if it's properly set. I can still edit orders, though cannot delete.

Comment: MAY BE YOUR STORE URL AND WEBSITE URL SAME LIKE : store url = https://www.exampal.com website url = https://www.exampal.com (with check http & https)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is now an older version of opencart, I still see this being reported a lot around and about.

The problem occurs due to the store front adding the http url rather than the https url to the order. So firstly you need to fix that. If you dont want to read all of my explanation, you can just hit up the bold points :)

Either way **BACKUP EVERYTHING** actually not really, back up the file you are going to edit and backup your whole database.

**open:**

```
catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php at around line 100
```

**Find:**

```
$order_data['store_url'] = HTTP_SERVER;
```

**Change to:**

```
$order_data['store_url'] = HTTPS_SERVER;
```

Now you will want to fix your database because for reasons I cannot fathom, the domain name is placed in the order along with the stores id. and when editing orders it is the usage of that directly within your admin order page that throws up the undefined notice. Basically the browser blocks the request because its trying to make an insecure request from a secure page.

Crack open phpmyadmin or whatever database tool you have on hand.

locate the table, default is **oc_orders**

Browsing the table, look for the column that contains your store url (i cant remember the name off hand, i think its just store_url but it will be obvious anyway. if you are multi store you will need to run the query for each

I am sure somebody can come up with a clever way to automatically convert just the http into https with a single use sql query on the one column, but this works for me.

**Run SQL: adjust as appropriate**

```
UPDATE `oc_orders` SET `store_url` = 'https://example.com' WHERE store_id = 0;
```